# Multivariate Polynomial Division Question

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, factoring

I am trying to solve the following question:

``Let $F$ be a field and let $F[x, y]$ denote the ring of  polynomials in the variable $x$ and $y$ with coefficients in $F$. Suppose $f(x,y)$ belongs to $F[x, y]$. Apply the Factor Theorem to the ring $F[x]$ to show that $f(x, x) = 0$ if and only if $(x-y)$ is a factor of $f(x, y)$. More generally, show that $y - g(x)$ divides $f(x, y)$ if and only if $f(x, g(x)) = 0$, for $g(x)$ in $F[x]$.''

If $(x-y)$ is a factor of $f(x, y)$ then obviously $f(x, x) = 0$. But how do I prove the converse? Is there a version of the Factor Theorem for $F[x, y]$ that I need to use?

Comment: Immediate consequence of the factor theorem - see my answer in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then for the ring $R[x]$ we have the Factor Theorem:

  Let
  $f\in R[x]$
  and let
  $r\in R$
  . Then in
  $R[x]$
  we have
  $(x-r){\,\mid\,}f\;$
  if and only if
  $f(r)=0$
  .

Now suppose $F$ is a commutative ring and $f\in F[x,y]$ is such that $f(x,x)=0$.

Let $R=F[x]$ and let $g\in R[y]$ be defined as $g(y)=f(x,y)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
f(x,x)=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
g(x)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(y-x){\,\mid\,}g\;\text{in $R[y]$}&&\text{$\Bigl($by the Factor Theorem for $R[y]\Bigr)$}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(x-y){\,\mid\,}g\;\text{in $R[y]$}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(x-y){\,\mid\,}f\;\text{in $F[x,y]$}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.